# get a textbox value which will keyup event rise html

Tags: php, jquery, html

```
<html>
<?php  for($i=1;$i<5;$i++){?>
    <input type="text" value="<?php echo $i; ?>" id="val".$i>
<?php } ?>
</html>
<script src="../jquery-3.1.1.js"></script>
<script>
    $("input").keyup(function()
    {
        alert($("#val").val());
    });
</script>
```

> **NOTE** I will try to get text-box value when key-up event fire but always first text box value display how i will get text-box value
>   which key-up event fire

Comment: Ids have to be **unique**

Comment: Bhargav Chudasama  check the answers below

Answer (score 2):

Use `this`

```
$("input").keyup(function()
{
    alert($(this).val());
})
```

By the way, the `id` attribute must be unique within the HTML document, see http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_id.asp

Answer (score 0):

use `alert($(this).val());` instead of `alert($("#val").val());`